# Cropped characters - iOS11 - Alert Dialog Ask

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

Cropped characters - iOS11 - Alert Dialog. How to fix it?
Does anyone know the reason why this is happening?

[image]

```
func settingsButtonPressed() {
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
   let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Anuluj", style: .cancel) { (action) in
}
   alert.addAction(closeAction)
   let restorePurchases = UIAlertAction(title: "Przywróć zakupy", style: .default) { (action) in
    self.restorePurchases()
}
   alert.addAction(restorePurchases)

   let refreshCatalogs = UIAlertAction(title: "Odśwież", style: .default) { (action) in
   self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
   alert.addAction(refreshCatalogs)
   let delPubs = UIAlertAction(title: "Usuń publikacje", style: .destructive) { (action) in
    self.deletePublications()
}
   alert.addAction(delPubs)
   present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce. I ran your exact same code (minus the calls in the handlers, of course) and this is what I see:

[image]

My suggestion would be: try just this part of your code in a plain vanilla project, just to persuade yourself that this should work. Then start thinking about how your real app is different. Perhaps you are messing with fonts or appearance in a way that causes this issue.